# Multiple Jenkins Masters using a Shared Slave pool

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to scale Jenkins for a large organization. Is there a way to have multiple Jenkins masters share a slave pool? For example, if I had 200 Jenkins Masters and I want them to share the same set of 50 Linux slaves.

That is, assuming each slave only has 1 executor, if Master A submits a job to the slave pool and it is running on Slave 1, if Master B submits a job to the slave pool, it would try to run on one of the other free slaves, since Slave 1 is already occupied.

I know multiple masters could share a single slave if I configured the slave to have a new workspace and executor for each master. However, I want to be able to set the slave up once, instead of having a slave.jar running on the slave for each master.

Cloudbees Op Center appears to provide this functionality, but looking for a way to do this with the Open Source version. If not, how difficult do you think it would be to extend Jenkins to have this functionality? I have Java development experience and have done a little work with Jenkins plugin development.

Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

As you've noted it's not hard to share slaves between masters, just setup multiple workspaces and each master will install it's own slave jar. The trick is to share resources properly.

One such resource manager is [Apache Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/). A [Jenkins Mesos plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/mesos-plugin/) exists enabling the creation of slaves on a managed cluster.

This approach is very new and Ebay have blogged on how they've evolved their Jenkins setup to use Mesos:

- [Ebay CI solutin part 1](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2014/04/04/delivering-ebays-ci-solution-with-apache-mesos-part-i/)
- [Ebay CI solution part 2](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2014/05/12/delivering-ebays-ci-solution-with-apache-mesos-part-ii/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, this looks really interesting. Haven't dug into this a lot yet, but this definitely seems to align with a lot of what we want to do. Will dig into this further, thanks again.

Comment: @mark-oconnor After two more years, can you confirm that the Mesos approach still works and scales well in production? Any things to worry about?

Comment: @sorin Two years is a lifetime in technology :-) These days I run Jenkins as a container on Kubernetes, with the Kubernetes plugin to run slave jobs.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Gearman Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gearman+Plugin) developed by Open Stack to handle sharing slaves by multiple masters.

Comment: Unfortunately it provides a huge overhead and our Jenkins master with ~2000 jobs and 32 slaves stopped responding, when we switched on the plugin. Also it is said, it does not work with Matrix projects.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd set up all the masters with a cloud plugin for slaves. For example, you could install the [kubernetes plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Plugin) or the [nomad plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Nomad+Plugin) and connect all masters up to the same kubernetes or nomad cluster. [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/) or [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) would take care of resource management, and the masters would only be submitting jobs to a shared pool of resources. This concept can easily be applied to other cloud providers, like AWS, but IMHO if you just want to set up an on-prem pool of resources for your jenkins masters from scratch, nomad is the easiest option.