# Jenkins error - Remote call on slave fails

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins build fails with error "FATAL: java.io.IOException: Remote call on "slave_node" failed hudson.remoting.RemotingSystemException: java.io.IOException: Remote call on "slave_node" failed.

```
at   hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:195)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.setProxy(Unknown Source)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl.setProxy(RemoteGitImpl.java:856)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.getClient(Git.java:133)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:677)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:669)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1010)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:484)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
at com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuild$MultiJobRunnerImpl.run(MultiJobBuild.java:134)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
at com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuild.run(MultiJobBuild.java:73)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on ffuas4eng01 failed
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:760)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:179)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.util.Secret
at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
at   sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:142)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getLong(Field.java:611)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1707)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:484)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:472)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:369)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:598)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:185)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:99)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at ......remote call to ffuas4eng01(Native Method)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1356)
at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:221)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:752)
... 17 more
```

I don't understand the issue. Could someone help me? The master and slave are correctly set up as far as i can see. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any "Caused By" part in the stack trace right after the stack trace that you posted? Are you using the same version in both the master and the slave? Same JVM?

Comment: Nope. These are the only errors on the page. But i think i know the reason for this. Two masters are connected to the same slave node. And it is done through SSH i think. So, if the other guy connected to this slave node, maybe my SSH public key in the slave might have been over written. That's one thing i can think of. Or is it right what i am thinking? And next question, is it possible to have two masters communicating with the same slave using 2 pairs of keys? Anything we need to take care during this?

Comment: The part of when two masters are sharing the slave is a bit beyond what I know, but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599571/multiple-jenkins-masters-using-a-shared-slave-pool

Answer (score 12):

This is a two-year old question, but for what it's worth, I had the same thing happen to me.  I fixed it by removing the slave and then adding it back in.  It was previously add and the log file showed it, so not sure what was wrong. At any rate, if this happens to anyone, give that a try.

Comment: This did not work for me. I tried with a different directory as "Remote file system" in node configuration.

Comment: But, the frequency of failure has decreased drastically. So, thanks for the suggestion. I will upvote it.

Comment: That works for me, but it's becoming frequent. Some our pipelines are test-only, so we don't know if tests fail or if it's this bug. I'd like to know what's the underlying issue :/

Comment: it worked for me when my agent got disconnected with exception "remote call on slave" failed but The "remote call failure" can happen due to several reasons, this workaround will work for some of those where the actually reason was a timely glitch. So, it is important to know the root cause and avoid such failure.

Comment: I was able to get past this by clicking "Disconnect" on the node and then relaunching the agent.

Answer (score 2):

I kill the java process and tried again with success.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an SSH permission denied issue for me. I discovered that by disconnecting and relaunching the node.